# Answer the question title or the question body?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247779/44992

While not answering the question posed in the title of the question, it does address a possible cause of the actual problem that the poster was actually trying to solve. Additionally, the other (non-deleted) answers don't answer the question posed in the title either.

I don't mind if my answer is a good candidate for deletion, but I'd like to understand the reasons for it (and also the inconsistency) since both comments on it appear to be by people unable to read beyond the first paragraph, and the other answers address the original question/problem even less than mine does.

Comment: If the question title doesn't match the question body, you should comment on that fact, and flag (or VTC) as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 4):

As is virtually always the case in the "why did you delete one bad post but not the other bad posts right next to it", it's because your post got flagged and the others didn't, so it's the only one we actually looked at (it showed up in the review queue and another user checked it).

The others were non-answers, so I would delete them, but since one of them was posted by the asker saying that they worked around the problem, and the question seems abandoned now, I just got rid of the whole thing. If somebody else does run into this problem again they can post a new question

Comment: Mine actually did answer the question in the body, just not the title which was asking about one particular way to solve the problem in the question body

Comment: @MarkKCowan From what I can tell it wouldn't actually solve the problem the asker was having, since the keyboard wasn't sharing bandwidth with other USB devices on a hub. Your answer is useful for the situation you were in, so I think the best solution is probably to [post your own question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=Why+do+my+keyboard+and+mouse+stop+working+when+my+backups+are+running%3F) for that situation and self-answer it